# How can i print two objects side by side in Java

Tags: java, tostring

I'm modeling a solution just to display (in console) the FreeCell card game. I have two classes `Home` and `FreeCells`.
Both have overridden `toString`, it is a common implementation abstracted out to a static method.

### Class Home

```
 public class Home {
    private final int MAX_CELLS = 4;
    private Stack<Card>[] homeCells;

    public Home() {
        this.suitToPlacements = new HashMap<>();
        this.homeCells = new Stack[MAX_CELLS];
    }


    public boolean addACard(Card card) {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Layout.draw(Arrays.stream(this.homeCells).filter(Objects::nonNull).map(Stack::peek).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
   }
```

### Class FreeCells

```
    public class FreeCells {
    private final int MAX_CELLS = 4;
    private List<Card> cells;

    public FreeCells() {
        this.cells = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public boolean addCard(Card card) {
        //some code
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Layout.draw(this.cells);
    }
}
```

### Class Layout

```
public class Layout {
    private final static int MAX_CELLS = 4;


    public static String draw(List<Card> cards) {
        StringBuilder box = new StringBuilder();
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildContent(cards));
        box.append("\n");
        box.append(buildHorizontalBorder());
        return box.toString();
    }


    private static String buildContent(List<Card> cards) {
        StringBuilder contentBox = new StringBuilder();
        contentBox.append("|");
        for (int index = 0; index < MAX_CELLS; index++) {
            contentBox.append(" ").append(index < cards.size() ? cards.get(index).toString() : "E ").append(" ").append("|");
        }
        return contentBox.toString();
    }

    private static String buildHorizontalBorder() {
        StringBuilder border = new StringBuilder();
        border.append("+");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_CELLS; i++) {
            border.append("----").append("+");
        }
        return border.toString();
    }
}
```

### Class Grid

```
public class Grid {
private List<Card>[] columns;

public Grid(List<Card> cards) {
    this.columns = new List[8];
    this.shuffle(cards);
}

private void shuffle(List<Card> cards) {
    while (cards.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; cards.size() > 0 && i < columns.length; i++) {
            Card randomCard = cards.remove(new Random().nextInt(cards.size()));
            if (columns[i] == null) {
                columns[i] = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            columns[i].add(randomCard);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    int cardCount = 0;
    StringBuilder layOut = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns[0].size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns.length && cardCount < 52; j++) {
            layOut.append(columns[j].get(i).toString() + "\t");
            cardCount++;
        }
        layOut.append("\n");
    }
    return layOut.toString();
}
}
```

### Class Board

```
public class Board {
    private FreeCells freeCells;
    private Home home;
    private Grid grid;

    public Board(FreeCells freeCells, Home home, Grid grid) {
        this.freeCells = freeCells;
        this.home = home;
        this.grid = grid;
    }

    public boolean canAddToHome(int columnNumber, int cardCount) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder boardLayout = new StringBuilder();
        boardLayout.append("Free Cell:\n").append(freeCells.toString()).append("\n").append("Home:\n").append(home.toString());
        boardLayout.append("\n");
        boardLayout.append(grid.toString());
        return boardLayout.toString();
    }
}
```

When I am printing the `board.toString()`, it looks like below, I have used newLine between the `freeCells` and the `home` objects  in the board's `toString`, which results in them being printed one under the other.

[image]

Is it possible to print the `freeCeels` and `home` side by side, so that e.g. the headings are in one line as shown below?

```
Free Cells      Home
+---------+    +-------+
| ...     |    | ...   |
+---------+    +-------|
```

Comment: this: boardLayout.append("\n"); Will make sure that you have a line underneath the first one.

Comment: You should create a backbuffer out of `char[]` and print on that, then flip that onto the screen.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't get how to do that